# Iterating Nightwatch task over array of URLs

Tags: nightwatch.js

I want to use [Nightwatch.js](http://nightwatchjs.org) to iterate over a collection of URLs in a system. My test is:

```
module.exports = {

'Checking URLs': function (browser) {
    var urls = [
        'https://google.com',
        'https://google.co.th'
    ];
    urls.forEach(url){
        browser
            .url(url)
            .waitForElementVisible('body', 3000)
            .assert.not.elementPresent('.booka-generic-php-error');
    }
    browser.end();
}

};
```

The urls are just for testing. I would expect the test to iterate over the urls, but an error is thrown:

```
urls.forEach(url){
```

unexpected token { on the line above.
What would be the correct way to iterate over a collection of URLs?

Comment: forEach(function(url){...});

Comment: ReferenceError: forEach is not defined - after I used "forEach(function (url) {" 

I am not sure if I mix up javascript styles.

Comment: I'm sorry. `urls.forEach(function(url){...});` Instead of ... put your function body.

Comment: that did the trick.. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should write that:

`urls.forEach(function(url){
   // your code there 
});`